# Тире перед словом ЭТО

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение: "Фронтон это верхняя часть стены сооружения со скатной крышей".

Вопрос. Тире необходимо перед словом *это*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире перед **это** в данном случае нужно ставить. **"Фронтон — это верхняя часть стены сооружения со скатной крышей".**

***В том случае, когда при сказуемом есть связка, тире перед ней ставится в обязательном порядке.*** Примеры: *Осень – это время для творчества и подведения итогов. Любить – это жертвовать собой. Усыновить ребенка – это подарок не ему, а прежде всего себе. Приходить всегда вовремя – это уважение не только к другим, но прежде всего к себе и своему делу.* http://fb.ru/article/171594/tire-pered-eto-kak-pravilno

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится перед словами **это, значит, это есть, вот** в предложениях, где сказуемое выражено именем существительным в именительном падеже. Как правило, эти слова служат для присоединения сказуемого к подлежащему, а также указывают на то, что сейчас последует сравнение или *определение*.

Ваше предложение является определением: **фронтон** (подлежащее) — **это часть** (сказуемое); тире необходимо.

Красота — это страшная сила.
Гипотенуза — это сторона прямоугольного треугольника, лежащая против прямого угла.
**Фронтон — это верхняя часть стены сооружения со скатной крышей.**
[**Когда ставится тире**](http://gramatik.ru/kogda-stavitsya-tire/)

Comment: _сооружения со скатной крышей._ Звучит так, будто скатную крышу имеет сооружение, а не часть фасада. (_Верхняя часть стены_ тоже слух режет.)

Comment: Есть вот такое определение. Оно очень похоже на то, которое присутствует в вопросе:  _**Фронто́н** от латинского (frons, frontis — передняя часть стены, лоб) — завершение фасадной стены строения, ограниченное двумя скатами крыши по бокам и карнизом у основания._  https://krovli.club/fronton

Comment: Да, это нормальное определение. Здесь уже понятно, что скаты крыши относятся к "завершению стены", а не к "строению". И "завершение фасадной стены" тоже звучит лучше, мне кажется, но здесь я категорично настаивать не буду.